# Unity, BoxCollider2D, Colliding but not trigerring

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

I have 3 gameObjects:
"Player" (with BoxCollider2D)
Weapon with (script attached, BoxCollider2D(isTrigger = true)) and "Enemy" with (BoxCollider2D, and tag "Enemy") I put a script to Destroy the enemy upon weapon to Enemy collison but it just goes past enemy until the player collider pusher the enemy.

````
{   
    private void onTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

That might be becuase you are using a collider, not a trigger.
Try use [OnCollisionEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) instead of `OnTriggerEnter`.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: It says Error: Has to be type: Collision2d 
so i changed it and same issue.
if IsTrigger is set to active it moves past. If is trigger is set to incative it pushes.
seems like it doesn't execute the If statement .....

Comment: argument is `Collision2D ` in the `OnCollisionEnter2D`

Comment: Alright ... I have no clue what happened but it's working now... With onTriggerEnter2D.
No clue what happened. Thank you for the help guys I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get any errors it looks like your handler method has invalid name in this context.

Change onTriggerEnter2D to OnTriggerEnter2D

Comment: did you mean onCollisionEnter2D?